# mapping cntrl+p , cntrl +n in command prompt

Tags: windows, command-line, bash, history

I m looking for  a way to map CNTRL+p  and CNTRL+n in command prompt to previous and next command in history. I m aware of F3 and up/down key but I m habituated to CNTRL+p/n on linux.

Comment: CMD also supports arrow keys (`↑`/`↓`) to navigate the command history. Pretty addictive hotkeys they are.

Comment: yeah I know about that , but its faster with cntrl+p/n as they are almost below the finger. Going and pressing those arrow keys is pain .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can translate <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd> to <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Down</kbd> keys with [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com).

```
^P::
    send {Up}
    return

^N::
    send {Down}
    return
```

You can limit the translation to happen only in Cmd.exe window:

```
^P::
    IfWinActive, Your-command-window-title...
    {
        send {Up}
    } else {
        send ^P
    }
    return

^N::
    (similar to above)
```

Well, I'm in Linux box, so I don't know the exact window title of cmd.exe, check it yourself.. Hope it works!